# SQL QUERY- How to remove repetitive days in sum function in "PIVOT" clause

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have a table abs_details that give data like follows -

```
PERSON_NUMBER       ABS_DATE            ABS_TYPE_NAME               ABS_DAYS
1010            01-01-2022              PTO                             1
1010            01-01-2022              PTO                             1
1010            06-01-2022              PTO                             0.52
1010            02-02-2022              VACATION                        1
1010            03-02-2022              VACATION                        0.2
1010            01-12-2021              PTO                             1
1010            01-12-2021              PTO                             1
1010            02-12-2021              sick                            1                   
1010            30-12-2021              sick                            1
1010            30-01-2022              SICK                            1
```

The output looks like -

```
 PERSON_NUMBER          ABS_TYPE_NAME   1  2   3 4 5 6    7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31   
    1010                    PTO         4               0.52
    1010                    VACATION           1   0.2
    1010                    SICK                                           1                                                        2
```

Using the query -

```
SELECT *
FROM
( 
    SELECT PERSON_NUMBER,
           EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DATE(ABS_DATE)) AS DAY_X,
           ABS_TYPE_NAME,
           ABS_DAYS
    FROM TABLE
    -- Add additional filter here which you want
 ) 
PIVOT(SUM(ABS_DAYS)
         FOR DAY_X IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31))
```

This is giving me the correct output mostly. But I want if for 2 dates say for example 01-01-2022 which has PTO twice, so the SUM of abs_Days for that date should be 1 and not 2. How can i tweak this inside the pivot function ?

Comment: Hard to say without possibility to replicate this. Maybe you could setup a fiddle for us? Can't you just use DISTINCT?

Comment: why abs_details has duplicate rows? There should be some distinction between them, you need to figure out and add that on condition to the query, or,  from the given data looks like you need you need distinct abs_dates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but it looks to me like the value of ABS_DAYS per every day in month (1 to 31, don't know why 0 is here) should not be greather then 1 (as like 1 day is 1 day max). In that case you should probably handle that in the Select clause...

```
SELECT 
    PERSON_NUMBER, ABS_TYPE_NAME, 
    CASE WHEN "0" > 1 THEN 1 ELSE "0" END "0", 
    CASE WHEN "1" > 1 THEN 1 ELSE "1" END "1", 
    CASE WHEN "2" > 1 THEN 1 ELSE "2" END "2",
    CASE WHEN "3" > 1 THEN 1 ELSE "3" END "3",
    CASE WHEN "4" > 1 THEN 1 ELSE "4" END "4",
    CASE WHEN "5" > 1 THEN 1 ELSE "5" END "5",
    CASE WHEN "6" > 1 THEN 1 ELSE "6" END "6",
--  ...
    CASE WHEN "30" > 1 THEN 1 ELSE "30" END "30",
    CASE WHEN "31" > 1 THEN 1 ELSE "31" END "31"
FROM
( 
    SELECT PERSON_NUMBER,
           EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DATE(ABS_DATE)) AS DAY_X,
           ABS_TYPE_NAME,
           ABS_DAYS
    FROM TABLE1
    -- Add additional filter here which you want
 ) 
PIVOT(Sum(ABS_DAYS)
         FOR DAY_X IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31))
```